# Get a modal from cards looping php (while loop)

Tags: php, mysql, function, while-loop, modal-dialog

I am trying to populate modals with data from mysql database, relating to the card that the user clicks on. The cards are generated by while loop - example below.

Right now my modal only shows the data relating to the first row of the database, no matter which card you click on. What is the easiest why to tie the card data to the modal?

```php
<?php
$result = $conn->query($query);

if (!$result){
    echo $conn->error;
}else{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row["size"]=='XLarge'){                            
            echo "<div class='col-4 col padding-small'>
            <div class='card' style='width: 100%'>
            <div class='card-body'>
            
                <h4 class='mybreed'>{$row["breed"]}</h4>
                <h5 class='card-subtitle'>Category: {$row["category"]}</h5>

                <div class='row flex-spaces child-borders'>
                <label class='paper-btn margin' for='modal-2' onclick='modal-2'>Learn about me!</label>
                </div>
                    
                <img class='image-bottom' style='width: 100%' src='{$row["image"]}'
                    alt='No image available'>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
            
            echo "<input class='modal-state' id='modal-2' type='checkbox'>
            <div class='modal'>
            <label class='modal-bg' for='modal-2'></label>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                <label class='btn-close' for='modal-2'>X</label>
                    <h4 class='modal-title'>Factfile: {$row["breed"]}</h4>
                    <p class='modal-text'>

                    <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Category:</td>
                        <td>{$row["category"]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Intelligence:</td>
                        <td>{$row["intelligence_category"]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Intelligence Rank:</td>
                        <td># {$row["intelligence_rank"]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Average Lifespan:</td>
                        <td>{$row["average_lifespan"]} years</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Average Shoulder Height & Weight:</td>
                        <td>{$row["shoulder_height_cm"]} cm / {$row["weight_kg"]} kg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Suitability for children:</td>
                        <td>{$row["suitability_for_children"]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Known Health Problems:</td>
                        <td>{$row["genetic_diseases"]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Cost of Ownership:</td>
                    <td>{$row["price_bracket"]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>";
        }
    } 
} 
$result->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: `id='modal-2` is a problem. Since you output this in a loop, you will have multiple elements with the same id, which is invalid in HTML. Id's must be unique within the document. When trying to reference an element by id, you'll always get the first match (since it only expect there to be one element with that id), which could explain your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the id to reference the unique id of the database row as it iterates, and that resolved the problem!